# Linq query in foreach

Tags: c#, linq

I want to clear my doubt regarding LINQ .
I have code like:

```
val collection = this.Employees.Where(emp => emp.IsActive)
foreach (var emp in collection)
 {
   // some stuff
 }
```

Now if I write code like this:

```
foreach (var emp in this.Employees.Where(emp => emp.IsActive))
 {
   // some stuff
 }
```

will `this.Employees.Where(emp => emp.IsActive)` be executed every iteration or it is executed only once?

Comment: Only once. Otherwise you would always be processing the 1st record.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can think of a `foreach` as this:

```
foreach (var x in y)
    // ...
```

as this:

```
T x;
using (var enumerator = y.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        x = enumerator.Current;
        // ...
    }
}
```

so the two pieces of code you showed will have the same effect.

A `for` however is different:

```
for (int index = 0; index < s.Length; index++)
```

Here `s.Length` will be evaluated on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 6):

It will be executed only once. To the runtime, both statements have the exact same effect.

Answer (score 0):

It will be executed only once...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: ok, will remember this next time... Thank you

Comment: By the way it was an automatic comment after reviewing in http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/